# TypeError while creating list of namedtuples: __new__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python, namedtuple

What I'm trying to accomplish is to create list, containing namedtuples, all that in loop. My code:

```
from collections import namedtuple

def selectMatch(self):
    match = namedtuple('ssid', 'quality')
    matches = []
    for point in self.discoverMatch():
            print(point)
            if point.ssid.startswith(''):
                    matches.append(match(point.ssid, point.quality))
    print([x.ssid for x in matches])
    return matches
```

And as a result, I'm getting TypeError mentioned in the title. My goal is to save namedtuples to list, but it says that I'm giving to much arguments and now I'm slightly confused.

Comment: Can you make the code *reproducible*?

Comment: Could you please provide full traceback into your question with an edit

Comment: `namedtuple` is a *class factory*. Please see the the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple). It seems totally crazy to create a new `match` class every time in your method. But anyway, the first argument is the *name* of the class, and the second argument defines the fields of the tuple. You have your tuple a single field, `quality`, but then when you try to create a `match` object with two fields.

Comment: after the first string, you should use a sequence, in `match = namedtuple('ssid', 'quality')`

Comment: @PRMoureu you can use a string, as well, `match = namedtuple('match', 'ssid quality')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields) takes a name and list of field names:

```
collections.namedtuple(typename, field_names, *, verbose=False, rename=False, module=None)
```

so you want `match = namedtuple('match', ['ssid', 'quality'])`.